# Can I undelete a note on iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, notes.app

I have Accidently deleted a note in the Note app and I really need it back! Tried a couple programs, like Phone Rescue, but my laptop virus protection said it was corrupt. Appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If you have backed up your iPhone with iTunes or iCloud before deleting the said note, you'll be able to get it back easily with a restore. There is no need to use third party software that pretend they can restore lost data because they will probably not work.